# jsfiddle using dojo not picking up styles for unknown reasons

Tags: javascript, css, dojo

I'm attempting to copy an [existing jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fzmeajL8/1/)

```
require([
"dojo/dom",
"dijit/Dialog",
"dijit/form/Button",
"dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
"dijit/layout/ContentPane",
"dojo/domReady!"
], function(dom, DijitDialog, Button, BorderContainer, ContentPane) {

(new Button({
    label: 'Show dialog',
    onClick: function() {


        var layout = new BorderContainer({
            design: "headline",
            style: "width: 400px; height: 400px; background-color: yellow;"
        });

        var centerPane = new ContentPane({
            region: "center",
            style: "background-color: green;",
            content: "center"                        
        });

        var actionPane = new ContentPane({
            region: "bottom",
            style: "background-color: blue;"
        });

        (new Button({ label: "OK"})).placeAt(actionPane.containerNode);
        (new Button({ label: "Cancel"})).placeAt(actionPane.containerNode);

        layout.addChild(centerPane);
        layout.addChild(actionPane);
        layout.startup();

        var dialog = new DijitDialog({
            title: 'dialog title',
            style: {
                //width: '400px',
                //height: '400px',
            },
            content: layout
        });

        dialog.containerNode.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        dialog.startup();
        dialog.show();   

    }

})).placeAt(document.body);
```

to a [new jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/crb66/er7ataLy/)

```
require([
```

. . .
})

that uses a newer version of dojo but the EXACT same code. I've added the external resource "claro.css" for the appropriate version of dojo that I'm using in the Frameworks setting, and the same LOAD TYPE in the JavaScript settings, but my fiddle is clearly missing styles since it is not rendering like the original: the dialog box and BorderContainer are missing borders, background colors, and essentially all styles.

This is even more important since the same thing is happening (styles not being applied) to a dialog dijit in an application that I'm working on.

What am I missing in my fiddle??

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the claro body tag. Click on Settings icon on HTML and add this to the body tag.

```
<body class="claro">
```

[image]

Comment: Please select it as the answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: how do i select it as the answer?  not seeing a link to do so.